# How would I change the shape of ggplot legend symbols?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to visualize the gapminder data set. Can someone help me get the legend to show round points with their sizes respective to the population of the country?

```r
df1<-gapminder[!(gapminder$country=="Kuwait"),]

blackline <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(continent, year) %>% 
  summarise(average = weighted.mean(gdpPercap))

p <- ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1960, 2000, by = 20)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Life Expectancy",
       y = "GDP Per Capita",
        color = "Continent",
        size = "Population (100K)") +
  # colored dots
  geom_point(df1, mapping = aes(col = continent, size = pop/100000)) +
  # colored lines
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(color = continent, group = country)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(continent)) +
  # weighted average black line
  geom_line(data = blackline, aes(x = year, y = average, size = 1)) +
  geom_point(data = blackline, aes(x = year, y = average, size = 1000))

p
```

[image: ggplot output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved by setting `show.legend=FALSE` in the geoms for the blackline:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df1<-gapminder[!(gapminder$country=="Kuwait"),]

blackline <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(continent, year) %>% 
  summarise(average = weighted.mean(gdpPercap))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'continent' (override with `.groups` argument)

p <- ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1960, 2000, by = 20)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Life Expectancy",
       y = "GDP Per Capita",
       color = "Continent",
       size = "Population (100K)") +
  # colored dots
  geom_point(aes(col = continent, size = pop/100000)) +
  # colored lines
  geom_line(aes(color = continent, group = country)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(continent)) +
  # weighted average black line
  geom_line(data = blackline, aes(x = year, y = average, size = 1), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = blackline, aes(x = year, y = average, size = 1000), show.legend = FALSE)

p
```

[image]